# Extract Substrings using regex Java

Tags: java, regex

I have a string that has several NP( ),  In between "NP(' and ')' is the data I want.
But i want just NP data inside not the first NP outside

How can I write a regex to extract "(DT a) (NN sign)" , "(DT the) (NN facade)" from the following text? I wnt for each text that contain NP to extract just inside NP data..I hope I explained well the problem

```
    (ROOT (NP (NP (DT a) (NN sign)) (PP (IN on) (NP (NP (DT the) (NN facade)) (PP (IN of) (NP (DT the) (NN building)))))))
```

Comment: See http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/trees/Tree.html#getLeaves%28%29

Comment: Please understand that SO is not a place where you come and drop your requirements so that other people start doing the work for you. In that sense - when asking for *code help*, please include the *code* that **you** wrote so far and explain where you are stuck.

Comment: I did it, and it gives me :  graph:
-> sign-NN (root)
  -> a-DT (det)
  -> facade-NN (prep_on)
    -> the-DT (det)
    -> building-NN (prep_of)
      -> the-DT (det)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex will match all the data that are you asking:

```
\(DT\s\w+.{3}NN\s\w+\)
```

Where `\(DT\s\w+` match the Determiner, thr white space and the string, `.{3}` match `) (` and `NN\s\w+\)` match the `Noun, singular or mass`.
Using regexpal match the data but if you want use it in Java code you need to escape the charactes so it will look like this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\(DT\\s\\w+.{3}NN\\s\\w+\\)");
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 33
\([DT\s[a-z]+\)\s\(NN\s[a-zA-Z]+\)

Comment: Ok, take a look now.

Comment: it works;;But it gives me just a sign not  the building and the facade :/